# reading from file and passing value as parameter in sql

Tags: python, mysql

when i type

```
SELECT word from xyz WHERE number = '+12340008933';
```

into phpmyadmin and run it, i get a valid query output.

However when i'm reading the number from file it doesn't return anything. For example

```
base_dir = "/home/jayjay/Desktop/scripts/"

filehandle = open(base_dir+"inputFile.txt",'r')
for number in filehandle.readlines():
    sql = "SELECT word from xyz WHERE number = '%s';"%number
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print row[0]
```

This returns nothing. at all. i've converted the input file from Unix2dos and viceversa assuming there might be a problem with the input file

Comment: Can you provide a sample of inputFile.txt and did you verify that you are actually reading the file? A simple print(number) in the outer for loop would ensure you are even touching the database. Also, I assume you just didn't include connecting to the database and creating the cursor?

Answer (score 2):

You should use parametrised SQL statements not string replacement which is prone to SQL injections. Also, you probably need to strip any whitespace surrounding the value read from the file. Try the following:

```
base_dir = "/home/jayjay/Desktop/scripts/"

filehandle = open(base_dir+"inputFile.txt",'r')
for number in filehandle.readlines():
    sql = "SELECT word from xyz WHERE number = %s"
    cursor.execute(sql, (number.strip(),))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print row[0]
```

Comment: MySQLdb uses %s for parameters not ?. Other than that this is spot on.

Comment: I missed the bit about _phpmyadmin_ so I was going with standard DBAPI. :)

Comment: Had missed putting the parameters in a tuple also. Thanks @Omnikrys!

Comment: Actually one will fly on its own with MySQLdb. Not sure how 'correct' it is but it works.